# sum of the elements of a list until limit

Tags: python

I am facing a problem where I need my code to add the element of a list until the sum gets as close as possible to a constant. Once the constant is reached, I need the code to store the sum, and also the sum of indexes (count how many variables it needed to reach that sum). I am a beginner in Python and this problem is giving a very hard time.

I have tryed a while loop as well as a for loop. At that point, I am kind of stuck and not sure if my method is accurate.

here is a concrete example of the logic. Assuming demand for period 1 is 10 and demand for period 2 is 23 and Q is 12. (Q here represent an optimal quantity). What I want to figure out is whether we should place an order in period 1 that includes demand for periods1+2, or if it is better to place 1 order at period 1 and another one at period 2. Q is what determines it, if demand for period 1 is closer to Q or cumulative demand for period 1+2 is closer to Q. In this example, |10-12| < |(10+23)-12|, therefore we want to record an order for period 1, and another one for period 2.

```py
def feeoq(q, demand):
    sum = 0
    prod = []

    for i in demand:
        sum = sum + i
        if abs(sum - q) < abs(sum + i - q):
            return prod.append(sum)

        else:
            sum = sum + i
```

I am not getting an error message but the function is not returning what I am expecting.

Comment: Consider posting a concrete example, i.e. a so called [mcve]. Basically not only mentioning that your code doesn't do what you expect,  but rather show what you expect - by means of a concrete list, a concrete constant to be reached and your expected output.

Comment: I am rewriting my code right now to illustrate my problem better. Thank you for the advice

Comment: Ok, perhaps you can also check if my approach in my answer goes in the right direction.

Comment: I am very impressed, your approach works and does exactly what i was (poorly) trying to describe. I did not think about using sublists, as well as an enumeration. I am very thankful for your help. The math behind this algorithm is  simple to understand and model, but I really struggle to translate it into Python code, would you have a particular advice on how I could improve my skills in this area? Thanks again!

Comment: Having read your example in the comments below (which is still lacking in your post btw... :) I  still don't really understand your problem/way of trying to solve it: Given a Q of 12, like in your example - what if the demand list starts as `[50, 20, ...]`? Shouldn't a proper algorithm calculate that in the first period you need 5*Q = 60 to cover the first 50? And then consequently for the next period only 1*Q, because there are still 10 left from the first period?

Comment: In reality, it is unlikely that Q would be 12 if demand for each period is that high. Q is calculated using the average demand over the horizon. Assuming that over the demand horizon, 50 and 20 are the highest demand and then it drops in the next periods to give an optimal quantity of 12, we would simply order 50.  50 being higher than Q we would not consider ordering for 2 periods at once. In my opinion, you just pointed out one weakness of this replenishment model. When there is a high variability in demand, the heuristic that I am trying to code does not give the best result.

Comment: pretty much, does not order a multiple of Q, it orders the closest demand value from Q

Answer (score 1):

You have repeated the `sum = sum + i` line. Once at the start of the loop and then in the else condition. I guess you should remove the first addition line and append sum + i.

Comment: Thank you! my goal with that line was to continue adding up the elements for the rest of the list. How else do you think I could go about doing that?

Comment: A function stops when you return some value. Maybe you should just print the value. Or if you need to store that, assign the value to a global variable. You can read about global vars here. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/

Comment: @Lelionjaune why was your goal to continue adding the rest of the list? You said right at the beginning that the task is to sum up _until the sum gets as close as possible_ to some constant.

Comment: I am sorry if I didnt correctly explained my problem, I tryed to make it as generic as possible. So what I try to do is sum up the first few values in the list, until it gets close to my constant and pretty much continue that until the end of the list. Because it is a production scheduling problem, I would like to know what quantity to produce, and for how many period it is going to last for and this for the entire forecast horizon, which the size of my list. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Sorry, at least not to me - however, I'm not a production planner, so... Anyway, what does _until_ mean in this context. I mean when you just continue doing the same like before, then there is no _until_. Or do you want to separate the whole list into sublists, in a way that _all those sublists_ summed up are equal to (more or less) the constant value q? In other words: _until_ is that point where your `sum` is set back to 0 and a new sublist starts...?

Comment: Let me give you a concrete example of the logic. Assuming demand for period 1 is 10 and demand for period 2 is 23 and Q is 12. (Q here represent an optimal quantity). What I want to figure out is whether we should place an order in period 1 that includes demand for periods1+2, or if it is better to place 1 order at period 1 and another one at period 2. Q is what determines it, if demand for period 1 is closer to Q or cumulative demand for period 1+2 is closer to Q. In this example, |10-12|  < |(10+23)-12|, therefore we want to record an order for period 1, and another one for period 2.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can talk about this as a base of discussion:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

L = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
q = 7

print(L)

def subs(L, q):
    sum = 0
    for i, e in enumerate(L):
        sum += e
        if sum > q:
            if abs(sum - q) > abs(sum - e - q):
                r = sum - e
                sum = e
                n = i - 1
            else:
                r = sum
                sum = 0
                n = i
            yield n, r
    yield i, sum

print(list(subs(L, q)))
```

*Explanation :*

Basically, this function first of all checks, if `sum` is bigger than `q`. Only if yes, you have two values of which not both are smaller or both are bigger than q. This is the prerequisite for your test, which one of both has the smaller distance to `q`.
Now, depending on which one is closer to `q`, the function returns `sum` or `sum - e`.

Now that I use here the verb *return* while using *yield* in the code: it's not a usual function but a [*generator*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). The main clue about this type of functions is, when they *yield* a value, you can think in a first step of the same like returning a value, with one important difference: the *function* itself does not *return* (i.e. does not end), but falls asleep, waiting for its next call, keeping its complete state including all the values calculated up to now, to then proceed right in the next line after *yield*, as if nothing happened before - until the next *yield* keyword.

In short: IMO exactly what you need if you want to sum up *until whatever* but do not really want to stop when *whatever* is reached... :)

Answer (score 0):

Just my point of view to the problem, as stated in my comment below your question:

*An algorithm, which calculates the number of needed orders of fixed quantities per order for every period, such that the demand is always covered.

Additionally the rest of every order, which was not covered in a certain period, is considered, so that eventually the demand of the next period can be covered with one order less.*

```
def calcOrder(demand, Q):
    result = []
    rest = 0
    for i, e in enumerate(demand):
        current = e - rest
        order = np.ceil(current/Q)
        result.append(int(order))
        rest = order * Q - current
    return result
```

---

*Example:*

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(793)

demand = np.random.randint(0, 51, 5)
Q = 12

demand
# array([50, 20, 19, 48, 25])

print(f'demand\tcurrent\torder\trest')
rest = 0
for i, e in enumerate(demand):
    current = e - rest
    order = int(np.ceil(current/Q))
    rest = order * Q - current
    print(f'{e}\t{current}\t{order}\t{rest}')

# demand  current order   rest
# 50      50      5       10
# 20      10      1       2
# 19      17      2       7
# 48      41      4       7
# 25      18      2       6
```

Comment: You are correct, the "rest" is the inventory left on hand at the end of the period. Currently, my heuristic is implying that I produce to fulfill exactly the demand for the period, my coding abilities being limited :') but it is definitely something that I will be looking into soon